# DropKick troubleshooting

Tags: jquery, web, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-dropkick

newbie in web..

Though particular question, I'd like to better understand how to troubleshoot things I see while using java scripts in my web pages.

I'm trying to use DropKick 1.0.0 on my drop down fields.
Put the below in the header - and now the drop downs are gone and cannot be seen (before that there are simple drop downs).

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/Site/../../Content/dropkick.css" type="text/css" media="all" />        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./../../Scripts/js/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

I opened F12 in chrome > Console, and didn't see any thing related to Java script stuff.

1. How in general do you guys troubleshoot those king of errors in UI?
2. is that a versioning thing or so?

Example of one field:

```
                <section class="form-field">
                    <select class="field" name="children-age" id="children-age-field">
                        <option value="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Child Age</label>
                </section>
```